# How to capture text between single quotes after a positive lookbehind?

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse an error string in order to return meaningful output in an API. Here is a sample of the error string:

`Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'email@test.com' for key 'UNIQ_8D93D649A0D96FBF'`

I am *attempting* to parse `email@test.com` out of this sentence. This is my current regex:

`/(?<=Duplicate entry ')(.*)'/`

I'm doing a positive look behind for `Duplicate entry '` which gets me to the beginning of the string that I want. Then I want to capture everything until I reach a single quote. However, this regex is capturing the following:

`email@test.com' for key 'UNIQ_8D93D649A0D96FBF'`

So my regex is capturing all the way to the final end single quote. My initial hunch is that I need to do a positive lookahead that's not-greedy.

Comment: Which language it is?

Answer (score 1):

### Brief

The issue you're experiencing is because quantifiers are greedy by default. Changing `.*` to `.*?` will fix your issue, but using `[^']*` is considered more correct (and also performs better) since it doesn't backtrack.

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'email@test.com' for key 'UNIQ_8D93D649A0D96FBF'
```

#### Output

```
email@test.com
```

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/CXwD2h/1)

```
(?<=Duplicate entry ')[^']*
```

Comment: *"using `[^']*` is considered more correct"* By whom? This needs a citation. If you don't have one then just write *"I think `[^']*` is more correct"*